# RKHUNTER does not recognise common options

Tags: security, rkhunter

At the bottom of rkhunter.conf (I also tried placing it separately in rkhunter.conf.local), and after checking for invisible chars,

> Unknown configuration file option: CRON_DAILY_RUN="false"
>
> Unknown configuration file option: CRON_DB_UPDATE="true"
>
> Unknown configuration file option: APT_AUTOGEN="true"

Comes up for `rkhunter -C`. rkhunter is Version 1.4.6-5 from Maintainer: Debian Security Tools on Debian 10.1.

I already tried purging and reinstalling. Inserting other options in rkhunter.conf.local, such as `UPDATE_MIRRORS=1` or `ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER = yes`, does not trigger a warning. Only these three give issues.

PS: I say rkhunter.conf.local but it doesn't matter, the result is the same if I edit rkhunter.conf directly.

Comment: What editor did you use to edit the file? What does the previous line (the non-blank one above the first error line) say - is it valid?

Comment: show (the relevant part of) `rkhunter.conf.local`

Comment: rkhunter.conf.local: i.imgur.com/CZp6Ni9.png @Bodo

Comment: @roaima when it was in rkhunter.conf, the previous line was either blank or a comment (I tried both). in rkhunter.conf.local see the comment above. I used nano to edit it, and already removed all CRLF and inserted again, all in nano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three options need to be set in /etc/default/rkhunter, not rkhunter.conf or rkhunter.conf.local!